# Why I can't get URL in webView

Tags: android, webview

Why i can not get the URL in the textView url? thanks so much for the help xP

```
public class Browser1Activity extends Activity {

TextView url;
WebView ourBrow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvURL);
    // cancel the web intent that default in android setting
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // webView seeting
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    try {
        ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.au");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    url.setText(ourBrow.getUrl());
}

    }
```

Comment: is an error being thrown?  Does ourBrow.getUrl() return the value you expect?  is url pointing to a valid object?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
TextView url = new TextView(this);
```

Maybe something was going wrong with the way the TextView was being created.

For your WebView, try this:

```
    WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    ourBrow.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: the TextView was setted in correct, but it seems I can't get anything from "ourBrow". any idea??

Comment: if this doesnt, work it's possible you may have to edit your wvBrowser file, but let me know if this works!

Answer (score 1):

you can get Url any time when page finished or page started

```
        WebView web=new WebView(this);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            // can get Here
            view.getUrl();
            //Now set to TExtView
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // can get Here
            view.getUrl();
            //Now set to TExtView
        }
    });
```